# populateWidget in search

Tags: javascript, applicationcraft

In Applicationcraft I have a search function. I want to display the 6 group names in a searchbox.

1. The first group is "ADMIN GROUP". I f enter "A" in a searchbox, I want to display "ADMIN GROUP".
2. The second group is "INSPECTION GROUP". If I enter " I " in a searchbox I want to display "INSPECTION GROUP".

Like this I want to display the following 6 groups in a searchbox,

1. ADMIN GROUP
2. INSPECTION GROUP
3. MANAGER GROUP
4. USER GROUP
5. GROUP 1
6. GROUP 2

Please help me How can I display the above groups in a searchbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<datalist>` element.

```html
<input list="group-list" type="text">

<datalist id="group-list">
    <option value="ADMIN GROUP">
    <option value="INSPECTION GROUP">
    <option value="MANAGER GROUP">
    <option value="USER GROUP">
    <option value="GROUP 1">
    <option value="GROUP 2">
</datalist>
```

Comment: I want to do this function in application craft. Need javascript client side code for this. Not html.

Comment: @kalidass Just use javascript to generate the HTML dynamically.